# how to make a asp.net application that can run on android mobile

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website based on database created using asp.net and I want to make it accessible to mobile phones, such that a user can use it through his/her cell phone.

Comment: *I want to make it accessible to mobile phones* which thing restricted to access from mobile? go to mobile browser, type your website address and access it.

Comment: you want to run an asp.net application on android? or do you want to access it while it is running on some sort of server?

because the first is not possible and the latter is just like accessing any other website, or rest api.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign the UI using responsive design, for this you can use ready made css frameworks like bootstrap. In this case, you only have to work on UI part, most of your backend code works fine.